# Where to set default AWS region for Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins v2.164.3

We use the [AWS Steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws) v1.38 in our Jenkins pipelines. We used to just be able to do

```
withAWS() {
  cfnValidate(file: 'myCloudFmtn.yaml')
}
```

But now I have to set the region to make the same call work.

```
withAWS(region: 'us-east-1') {
  cfnValidate(file: 'myCloudFmtn.yaml')
}
```

We use the `withAWS()` call in a LOT of places so I don't really want to do this. Is there a way to set the default AWS region in Jenkins system configuration?

Comment: Possibly encapsulating it within a helper method, but otherwise probably not according to the plugin documentation.

Comment: Yeah it kinda sucks. I opened a Github issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jenkins declarative pipeline, you can set this as environment variable that gets picked up by AWS SDKs. Note that in my example below, I'm using 2 of these variables to cater for multiple versions of SDKs (thouh in case of JavaSDK used by aforementioned plugin, only `AWS_REGION` would suffice acording to [AWS SDK Docs for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html)

This answers takes as an assumption that someone did not hardcode the default region in the plugin code itself.

```
pipeline {
  environment {
      AWS_REGION = 'ap-southeast-2'
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = 'ap-southeast-2'

  }

  stages {
     // your pipeline code here
  }

}
```